# Structured Bindings Order and Evaluation

Tags: c++, structured-bindings

Sorry for the bad title to this question, but I really couldn't think of a better way to title it.  My question involves structured bindings and maps, but couldn't really find anything in the standard that could give me a cast-iron guarantee.  Consider the following:-

```
struct Obj {};

std::map<int, Obj> data;

if (const auto&[o, state] = data.insert(std::make_pair(0,  Obj())); state)
{
    // state is true if the object was inserted
}
else
{
    // Is it guaranteed that Obj() won't get called for a case where the key already exists?
    // Does the key get checked for its existence BEFORE the evaluation of the make_pair()?
}
```

At what point is the key evaluated for its existence, or is this a case of everything will be evaluated from the inside to the outside (so Obj() created, then make_pair(), then .insert attempted etc.

Comment: How could you check if the key exists without constructing the `Obj` part of the pair you pass to `insert`?

Comment: You can call `data.find(0)` explicitly but yes, to call `insert`, you need first to completely create the argument. Like any other function call.

Comment: "_At what point is the key evaluated for its existence_" Just the same as it would be if you were not using structured bindings. The `insert()` is done, then its results are assigned (result is decomposed/bound) to `o` and `state`, then `state` is checked. The `insert()` is passed a default-constructed `Obj()` by you, to compare against, so of course that `Obj()` must be constructed whether the key exists or not, to compare to it. What are you **really** asking? i.e.: (a) Do you 'need' (want) to avoid default/constructing an `Obj()` if it exists, somehow, and (b) Are you unsure how SBs work?

Comment: I get what you're saying, makes sense...  I was just trying to see if I could get away without having to do a .find().  But in the above example, that would mean that if the key exists, the Obj() would get constructed and destructed if the key exists.  I guess that's why you usually only store pointers in maps.

Comment: @underscore_d With .find, you can just pass a key, you don't need to construct Obj(), so that's why this is different.  You can determine if a key already exists without ever constructing Obj().

Comment: @TheWelder You're right; I had a brain-o :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the key get checked for its existence BEFORE the evaluation of the make_pair()?

No, that is not how C++ evaluates expressions. `std::make_pair(0,  Obj())` is fully evaluated, the pair is constructed before it is passed to `insert` method, or any other callable for that matter. So `Obj` always exists before the function is even called.

Implementing this feature would require some form of lazy evaluation.

But there is a solution exactly for this kind of problem - [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace):

```cpp
struct Obj {
   Obj(std::string, float, int);
};
int key=0;
data.try_emplace(key, "Str", 0.2f, 5)
```

This will first check if key exists, if it does, the arguments are not moved from and `[iter,false]` is returned. Otherwise `Obj("Str",0.2f,5)` is constructed in-place with perfect forwarding and returns `[iter,true]`. The post condition is that the returned iterator is always pointing to a pair equal to the parameters.

Another upside of this solution is you no longer need to use the ugly `std::piecewise_construct` tag for ordinary `emplace`.

Comment: Nice...  Hope nobody minded the question...  I was just seeing if I could avoid doing a .find() on the key, before doing an .insert().  I understand SB and when I re-read my question, I can see how much sense it didn't make!  Nice demonstration of try_emplace() though, didn't think about that!

Comment: @TheWelder I think the only reasonable use case of `insert` is when you want to insert a range. I think I always use `try_emplace` for single insertion now because it has the best syntax. It can accept `std::move(precreated_obj)` and just call the move constructor if you already have an object ready.